# How to add a metabox in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php
function prfx_custom_meta()
{
add_meta_box(
    'some_meta_box_name'
    ,__( 'Some Meta Box Headline', 'plugin_textdomain' )
    ,'render_meta_box_content' //this is callback function.
    ,'post_type'
    ,'advanced'
    ,'high'
);

}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'prfx_custom_meta' );
?>
```

> I used the above code to create a metabox in Wordpress. But , for that
>   code it doesn't showing up
>   couldn't find the solution. kindly suggest any ideas for that problem
>   .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on where you want the metabox to appear.

If you want it to appear on posts then you need to use

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'add_post_metabox' ) ){
    function add_post_metabox(){
        add_meta_box('post-meta', esc_html__('My Metabox', 'mytheme'), 'My_Metabox_function', 'post', 'side', 'low');
    }
}

add_action('admin_init', 'add_post_metabox');
```

And then create metabox with

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'My_Metabox_function' ) ){
    function My_Metabox_function( $post ){
        //metabox layout and variables here
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'My_Metabox_save_function' ) ){
    function My_Metabox_save_function($post_id){
        global $post;
        if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){
                return $post_id;
            } else{
                //do save here
            }
        }
    }


add_action( 'save_post', 'My_Metabox_save_function' );
```

If you want it on page then you can create it like above but with page instead of post

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'add_page_metabox' ) ){
    function add_page_metabox(){
        add_meta_box('page-meta', esc_html__('My Metabox on Page', 'mytheme'), 'My_Metabox_page_function', 'page', 'normal', 'high');
    }
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_page_metabox');
```

You can hook to `admin_init` of `add_meta_boxes` hooks. See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) for more explanation.

You can put it in your `functions.php` file or you can set it in separate `.php` file and call it in `functions.php` with something like:

```
require_once( get_template_directory(). '/include/metaboxes.php' );
```

This will include `metaboxes.php` that are located in the `/include` directory of your theme.