# Add new metabox on right side under the categories (post type)

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

When in dashboard you click on Add new post, you can see ttitle description on left side and category and other option on other side. I have to add two more widgets, first one just like featured image which I managed to add using "multiple post thumbnail", and another widget where user can add urls. Can I get help from anybody plz?

Comment: It's not very clear what you need. Metabox? What kind of metabox? Adding metabox is easy, you can follow answer I gave recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472587/how-to-add-a-metabox-in-worpress/33473235#33473235 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490961/woocommerce-product-image-overwriting-my-featured-image-wordpress/33494327#33494327 with a detailed description on how to add another featured image in a metabox. Combine this to get the result you need...

Comment: thanks, yes I want to add meta box, where user have textbox to enter something, and have option to add more. Just like "Add another category".

Comment: thnx  dingo_d, how can make it loop, so that user can add multiple data through text box.

Comment: also how to save the data, because when I enter something and click update, after refrresh it get disappears..

Comment: function cd_meta_box_cb( $post )
{
 global $post;
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $text = isset( $values['my_meta_box_text'] ) ? $values['my_meta_box_text'] : '';
 
echo '<p>';
   echo '<label for="my_meta_box_text">Link Url</label>';
   echo '<input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text" id="my_meta_box_text" value="'.$text.'" />';
       echo '</p>';
      
}

I used this to save my vamlue but still it gets vanished on rfresh....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involves registering metaboxes for the post type in the [`register_post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#register_meta_box_cb) function and then doing the saving procedures using the [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) (or similar) WordPress hook. Create the UI in the metaboxes, then inside `save_post` you can read the values contained in `$_POST`.

Assuming a metabox contains a field such as

```
<input type="text" name="my-text-field">
```

then you can save the value as post meta in `save_post`

```
add_action('save_post', function ($postId, $post, $update) {
    $textValue = $_POST['my-text-field'];

    update_post_meta($postId, 'text_value', $textValue);
}, 25, 3);
```

I skipped post type and data validation to keep the example simple. You should always check that the data is valid and is not saved if not needed or if it is considered harmful.

The metabox fields should always be included in `$_POST` by using regular HTML inputs. You can wrap those inputs into a JS UI if you need stuff like galleries and colors picker.

Comment: ok thanks. Now how to create a loop, if I want to allow user add more than on values?

Comment: or you can say that how to add "add more button"?

Comment: That involves Javascript. You need to create a hidden clone element which can be cloned and appended to the list as a new empty element.